# Remove line breaks in CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

In need open my **CSV file** and replace the line breaks in column number 44 in c#.

This is the string on the CSV file :

```
9|D60||08/12/2018 19:09:19|08/12/2018 19:30:07|00:20:48|08/12/2018 22:00|A|L|M|D60 SM |D60 MA    |0|19|0|3175|0|3|00:03:25|20,98|0,017|0|0|NO|NO|-|CO|CH|CA|-|D60 - B|DP6 - F|DP6 - L|NO|-|-|DP6 - L|- - -|ND|ND|NO|-|NO|--dic

-acc |-|-|0|0|
```

I have tried withous success this code :

```
   output = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("csv/target_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv")
   string so = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(output);
   string[] arr = so.Split('-');
   for (int i = 2; i < arr.Length; i = i + 44)
      {
         arr[i] = arr[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
       }
   string res = String.Join("", arr);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(output, res);
```

For this new output with only one line :

```
9|D60||08/12/2018 19:09:19|08/12/2018 19:30:07|00:20:48|08/12/2018 22:00|A|L|M|D60 SM |D60 MA    |0|19|0|3175|0|3|00:03:25|20,98|0,017|0|0|NO|NO|-|CO|CH|CA|-|D60 - B|DP6 - F|DP6 - L|NO|-|-|DP6 - L|- - -|ND|ND|NO|-|NO|--dic-acc |-|-|0|0|
```

How to do resolve this ?

Comment: Do not read entire file with ReadAllText.  Either read file one line at a time or put string into StringReader.

Comment: You're replacing all newlines by nothing (`""`). Why do you expect to have newlines in the result?

Comment: @jdweng: how does reading the file in a different way solve the logical problem in his code?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for reply, I need in output the string in only one line.

Comment: Then I didn't get the question, sorry.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm sorry Sir... I have a string that at some point is sent to the new line ... I need this string in only one line....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's try new approach.

The idea is to read in the csv file line by line. Then, foreach line, check how many fields there are by splitting it on the pipe symbol separator character.

If there are less then 49 fields (that is how many fields I counted in your example), append the next line to it.
Store all these lines (rows) in a List and finally output that as a new file.

```
int fieldsExpected = 49;  // I have counted 49 fields per row of the CSV file. You should check this!
string fileOut     = "<PATH-AND-FILENAME-FOR-THE-OUTPUT-CSV>";
string fileIn      = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("csv/target_" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv");

// Read the file line by line.
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileIn);
List<string> newLines = new List<string>();

// If your csv file has a header row, uncomment this next line
// newLines.Add(lines[0]);
// and have the loop start at 'i = 1'
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    string temp = lines[i];
    // Split the line on the separator character. In this case the pipe symbol "|"
    string[] fields = temp.Split('|');
    // Check if the number of fields in this line is correct.
    // It will be less if any of the fields contained a line break.
    // If this is the case, append the next line to this one.
    while (fields.Length < fieldsExpected && i < (lines.Length - 1)) {
        i++;
        temp += lines[i];
        fields = temp.Split('|');
    }
    newLines.Add(temp);
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileOut, newLines.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now it's perfect !

Answer (score 1):

You could remove line breaks right after this code:

```
string so = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(output);
// replace line break here
so = so.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Now variable `so` will contain `"9|D60||08/12/2018 19:09:19|08/12/2018 19:30:07|00:20:48|08/12/2018 22:00|A|L|M|D60 SM |D60 MA    |0|19|0|3175|0|3|00:03:25|20,98|0,017|0|0|NO|NO|-|CO|CH|CA|-|D60 - B|DP6 - F|DP6 - L|NO|-|-|DP6 - L|- - -|ND|ND|NO|-|NO|--dic-acc |-|-|0|0|"` without any line breaks.

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate data in each column with the `pipe |` in your CSV or are the pipes within the string?

Comment: The `pipe |` is within the string... In this case  I have a string that at some point is sent to the new line ... I need this string in only one line

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint on 3rd line of code, does `so` contain the long string with the line break? Sorry I'm just trying to understand relation between CSV file type and string shown, as the code I've given can replace line breaks within a string. Usually CSV files have data separated by commas for obvious reasons so slightly confused here with the explanation.

Comment: The data source is an Excel file and the CSV is saved with `pipe |` because it's possible on the string to find `commas`. In the Excel and CSV file is normally all lines are on the same line... but in this case the line is sent to the new line because ont he Excel File in the column 44 the text contained it's on two lines.
I need this string in only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following ? (replacing \n\r instead of only the Env.newline)

```
var output = @"C:\TEMP\target.csv";
string so = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(output);

Console.WriteLine("without replace");
Console.Write(so);

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("with replace");
Console.Write(so.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have change on my string.

Comment: the output is only to show that it stays on one line instead of 2 !  Why isn't that working for you to make the double replace ?

Comment: With your code I  don't have replace... the CSV not change, I have this string in two lines instead of one : `... B|DP6 - F|DP6 - L|NO|-|-|DP6 - L|- - -|ND|ND|NO|-|NO|--dic

New line
-acc |-|-|0|0|`

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland `String.Replace` is not an action that modifies a string. It is a function that creates a _new_ string. Nothing can modify a string; the `String` class is immutable. You have to _assign_ the result to a string variable again.

Answer (score 0):

The following code opens a file and removes line breaks from the string in the file :

```
static string OpenFileWithoutCRLF()
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader("LineBreak.txt");
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""); 
    }
```

.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") removes line breaks.

Comment: AFAIK This does exactly what the OP wants.